# Mobile performance with bitmapData.draw()

Tags: actionscript-3, air

i'm making a drawing mobile application with Air, in fact it's a single line moving with the accelerometer.

I notice performance issue on Android, the framerate goes to 20fps (flash framerate is set to 60fps).
When the draw is done, it gets to 60 fps again. The drawing is only a single 2 pixels width line, and there's not much assets (converted to bitmap).

Here is my enterFrame function :

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, render);

function render(evt:Event):void{    
evt.stopPropagation();      


brush.graphics.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
canvasData.draw(brush);

}
```

point.x / point.y is defined with the accelerometer in a AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE  event. Maybe that both events in the same time are not a good idea ?

thanks for anyone finding a solution :)

Comment: Bitmap encoding/decoding is incredibly slow on mobile devices. I've developed 4 fairly large AIR apps now and I have yet to come across a device that can handle it well, on Android or iOS.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try to improve that but if i can't the 20fps is not really annoying.. Very strange for only a little line :)

Comment: If you don't need 60fps, I suggest dropping it down to 30fps. It gives you much more room to work with.

Comment: You don't seem to clear the graphics prior to drawing that line. `draw()` has to complete the entire GraphicsPath to draw a Shape, and if that path is really long, the draw is really slow.

Comment: Try drawing on user input instead of enterframe event and lock the bitmap while drawing.

Comment: I finally didn't use bitmapdata, i only use the graphics on the screen. The result is smoother, and fps is 52/60... I tested and my android phone, not on ios for the moment (i have to re-buy the developer licence :(  )